# Conversion of timestamp/varchar column to bigint in presto which contains two different date formats

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, presto, opera-presto

I have a source table `click` with a column named `click_date` whose datatype is `varchar`, it contains values with two different format of dates in the same column. For example:

```
Jul 17 2018 4:54PM
2019-02-05 08:20:29.000
```

I have a target table named `click` and I need to map the data into it in a column named `click_date` whose datatype is `bigint`.

So it is throwing an error while doing casting

Tried the below :

```
td_time_parse(cast(cast(click_date as timestamp)as varchar))
```

But it doesn't solve both the formats.. I need to convert both the date formats into integer so that it can be loaded into the target.

note that target data type cannot be changed and it is bigint. Фny leads will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output? if you want to convert into date, how can the output data type be int? Please be more clear and add examples for output

Comment: For example: I want to convert 2018-08-24 18:42:16 to 1535136136000

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `date_parse` and `to_unixtime` to convert your date in varchar into a unixtimestamp (which is in double datatype).

for date format: 2019-02-05 08:20:29.000

```
to_unixtime(date_parse('2019-02-05 08:20:29.000','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))
```

for date format: Jul 17 2018

```
to_unixtime(date_parse('Jul 17 2018','%b %d %Y'))
```

This will return you a double datatype of your date which you can store it in your database.

Comment: Hi Rishu , actually the other format was a typo.. it is like:  this May 26 2017 4:57PM , so the above logic is not working . Can u pls help with the updated one .. also for the first format  for . 000 it is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to handle both formats of dates with one expression. It essentially looks if the date/timestamp starts with a numeric or not.

```sql
select 
if(click_date rlike '^[0-9]', unix_timestamp(click_date ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), unix_timestamp(click_date,'MMM dd yyyy')) as click_date_mod 
from click;
```

Comment: Thanks Prabhat for the help. But these functions doesn't work in presto.. Can you please help if possible to do the same which works in presto engine.